# Custom slider in Unity Inspector

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, 3d, editor

This is an example of slider:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
[Range(0.0f, 10.0f)]
public float mySliderFloat;
..
}
```

But I want Min-Max values of the slider to be dependent of screen resolution (to set these Min-Max values dynamically in every frame) Could you provide me with an example?

Comment: By the way, in 99% cases you want to use `[SerializeField] private` instead of `public`.

Answer (score 1):

> Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the
> following types:
>
> Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
>
> string System.Type enums object (The argument to an attribute
> parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above
> types.)
>
> One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types (emphasis
> added by me)

So technically you cant do this. If you want to set the min and max value of a variable during runtime you need to use `Mathf.Clamp(value,min,max)`. Read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) from the unity docs. This way you can dynamically set min and max and change the desired value between them in a Update() method.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but as stated not with the default range attribute. You'll need to write a [custom inspector](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector) with your own [slider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Slider.html) using the variable values you want to use.